# Identity type in Rackspace in python

Tags: python-2.7, rackspace, pyrax

For Authenticating in Rackspace I got following code from Reckspace documentation

```
import pyrax

pyrax.set_setting("identity_type", "rackspace")
pyrax.set_default_region('{region}')
pyrax.set_credentials('{username}', '{apiKey}')
```

I don't get what is meant here by identity type please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you must set the identity_type setting so that can use the correct identity class. Prior versions only worked with Rackspace identity, but that is no longer the case. If you don't want to use a configuration file or an environment variable, you can do this in code:

pyrax.set_setting("identity_type", "keystone")
or

pyrax.set_setting("identity_type", "rackspace")
 [details here](https://github.com/rackspace/pyrax/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md)

Comment: eida ami agei paisi kintu identity type mane bujhi nai. up dilam but answer ta accpt korle ar keu jodi ans na dey tai dilam na but dui tin diner moddhe keu ans na dile accpt dimu ne.